# Find specific key in a div/class array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm appending words from a javascript array to a div class `bank-word`, which adds all words to a word bank for the user:

```
for (obj in words) {
    for (key in words[obj]) {
         $(".wordBank_Words").append("<div class='bank-word' word='" + key + "' ><b>" + key + "</b>: " + words[obj][key] + "</li>");
    }
}
```

If the user clicks a word in the word bank, it adds that word to a text box, and hides it from the word bank:

[image]

```
$(".bank-word").click(function (event) {

    //append each newly selected word to text box
    $('#textBox').val($('#textBox').val() + " " + $(this).attr('word'));

    //hide word from word bank
     $(this).hide();
```

Then if a user deletes the word from the text box, I want the word to reappear in the word bank as an option. This is the part I'm having trouble with. I'm able to check if the word no longer exists in textbox array with `isInArray(key, array)`, but am having trouble with checking the word bank to see that it doesn't yet exist in the word bank using `isInWordBank(key)`  (meaning, the user has selected the word before, thus hiding it from the word bank). Now it needs to reappear in the word bank since it's been deleted from the text box.

My question is, how can I use `jQuery.inArray` to pass in the word I'm looking for, and the div class array holding the word. I though it would be `jQuery.inArray(word, $(".wordBank_Words"))`. I thought I could just use jQuery `find()` with `each()`, but that won't let me get the specific key from the div class.

```
for (obj in words) {
    for (key in words[obj]) {

  //if word doesn't exist in text box array, and doesn't exist in word bank, add it back to word bank
    if (!isInArray(key, array) && !isInWordBank(key)) {
        log(key + " doesn't exist in text box array or word bank");
            //add word back to word bank
        }
    } 
}
```

Checks if word is in Text Box array:

```
function isInArray(word, array) {
  return array.indexOf(word) > -1;
}
```

Supposed to check if word is in the word bank at all:

```
function isInWordBank(word) {
//search through word bank for key
    jQuery.inArray(word, $(".wordBank_Words")) 
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="textBox"  value="" />
<br/>
<button onclick="submitMe()" id="testButton" >Submit Response </button>
<br/>

<div class="wordBank_Headings">Word Bank:
    <span class="wordBank_Words"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having a little trouble parsing through your code, but what I think you're going for is something like this:

```
$('#textBox').on('change', function(){

    var words = $(this).val().split(' ');

    $('.bank-word').each(function(){

       if( words.indexOf( $(this).attr('word') ) !== -1 ){
           $(this).hide();
       }

       else {
           $(this).show();
       }

    });

});
```

Does that work for what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Holy crap yes... I spent so much time trying to hack that together when there is already a wonderful jQuery function built for that. Thanks so much! Can you explain `if( words.indexOf( $(this).attr('word') ) !== -1 ){`? in this case, what is the `this` referring to? I see there are two `this`, but each pertains to something different

Comment: When I add `log("WORD: " +$(this).attr('word'));`, and delete a word from the text box, why does it return all values instead of the word being unhidden?

Comment: Sure thing. So `$(this).attr('word')` refers to the `word` attribute of the word-bank item currently being looked at, and we're looking at the words in the text box (split up by spaces) to see if there's a match. `indexOf` simply checks if it exists, with `-1` meaning it doesn't.

Comment: Because that part of the function loops through all the word bank items, not just what was changed. You could definitely optimize this a lot more to only look at the specific words/characters changed in the text box, but it would go beyond the needs of this SO question.

Comment: Nope I completely understand that. I was just curious :)

Comment: Do you need to use split? I removed it and it works fine without it. Also, if I put `log($(this).val());`, it logs the remaining words in the text box. Is that what `change()` function does for the textbox, just gets current remaining values?

Comment: You would need split because of shared letter collisions in words like hao vs haoma or something (I don't know Chinese, just an example.) If you compare against the string without splitting it, looking specifically for hao will find haoma and say it's there when they're different words.

Comment: The `change` event listener fires when the contents of the input element are altered and you click away (lose focus), like adding or removing a letter. There are other listeners you can use if you want a more instant response, like `keyup`, which immediately fires as soon as you do something with your keyboard in the input box.

Comment: Great. Thanks for everything